# spring jpa @Query error, expecting CLOSE, found '('

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, jpql

I have a following mysql query which works fine:

*Edit: the path is just for illustration purpose... I did not want to copy my packages...

```
select COUNT(IF(amount > 0, amount, 0)) as creditCount,
       COUNT(IF(amount < 0, amount, 0)) as debitCount,
       SUM(IF(amount > 0, amount, 0)) as credit,
       SUM(IF(amount < 0, amount, 0)) as debit,
       SUM(amount)                    as balance,
       cp.surname, cp.id, pcp.number from prepaid_card_transaction_pojo pctp
         join prepaid_card_pojo pcp on pctp.account = pcp.id
         join customer_pojo cp on pcp.id = cp.prepaid_card
where pcp.number = '1000765352' AND pctp.client = UUID_TO_BIN('fb9dbcac-cd03-46ad-94b0-2709b0b0e2a8') AND booking_time > '2020-12-01 00:00:00' group by cp.id;
```

I wish to transfer it to jpql:

```
@Query("select new path...Bean(" + //
            "COUNT(IF(pctp.amount > 0, pctp.amount, 0))," + //
            "COUNT(IF(pctp.amount < 0, pctp.amount, 0)), " + //
            "SUM(IF(pctp.amount > 0, pctp.amount, 0)), " + //
            "SUM(IF(pctp.amount < 0, pctp.amount, 0)), " + //
            "SUM(pctp.amount), cp) " + //
            "FROM PrepaidCardTransactionPojo pctp " + //
            "JOIN PrepaidCardPojo pcp ON pctp.account = pcp.id " + //
            "JOIN CustomerPojo cp ON pcp.id = cp.prepaid_card " + //
            "WHERE pcp.number =:voucherNumber AND pctp.client =:client AND booking_time >= :from AND booking_time < :to GROUP BY :customer")
    List<Bean> loadGroupedCustomerPrepaidTransactions(@Param("client") ClientReadable client, @Param("customer") CustomerReadable customer, @Param("voucherNumber") String voucherNumber, @Param("from") Date from, @Param("to") Date to);
```

I am getting a following error:
`...QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found '(' near...`

Comment: do you think this is correct

new path...Bean(........

Comment: @RaushanKumar he wrote Bean for the sake of simplicity, I think.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think JPQL has `if` - so you would have to use CASE WHEN ... ELSE ..., like so:

`SELECT e.name, CASE WHEN (e.salary >= 100000) THEN 1 WHEN (e.salary < 100000) THEN 2 ELSE 0 END from Employee e`

more here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL_BNF#New_in_JPA_2.0

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `nativeQuery = true` which indicates that query is native MySql query, not Jpql query.

```
@Query("select ...", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Bean> loadGroupedCustomerPrepaidTransactions(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to like this :

```
@QUERY(nativeQuery = true, value = "select COUNT(IF(amount > 0, amount, 0)) as creditCount,
       COUNT(IF(amount < 0, amount, 0)) as debitCount,
       SUM(IF(amount > 0, amount, 0)) as credit,
       SUM(IF(amount < 0, amount, 0)) as debit,
       SUM(amount)                    as balance,
       cp.surname, cp.id, pcp.number from prepaid_card_transaction_pojo pctp
         join prepaid_card_pojo pcp on pctp.account = pcp.id
         join customer_pojo cp on pcp.id = cp.prepaid_card
where pcp.number = :voucherNumber AND pctp.client = :client AND booking_time > :from AND booking_time < :to group by cp.id)
List<Bean> loadGroupedCustomerPrepaidTransactions( ClientReadable client,  CustomerReadable customer,  String voucherNumber, Date from, Date to);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. After a couple of hours tuning this here are the lessons learned:

- JPQL doesnt like column aliases...
- JPQL doesnt like IF (was using
  "COUNT(IF(pctp.amount > 0, pctp.amount, 0))", should use:
  "COUNT(case when pctp.amount > 0 then 1 else 0 end),"
- JPQL COUNT should operate with the number as how many times the match should be counted - the specific 1 in above example. While mysql goes simply by the condition matching value as 1
- all listed attributes should come by pojo designation not by DB column designation as I did in initial post in case of cp.prepaid_card